# Installing package "locClass" in R

Tags: r, package, devtools, install.packages

I'm trying to install the R package "locClass" in RStudio with the following command:

```
install.packages("locClass", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

However, it fails to install. I get the following warnings and error message:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0/12.0.1'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [locClass.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘locClass’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/locClass’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘locClass’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've also tried installing the package directly from the github page https://github.com/r-forge/locclass using `devtools::install_github("r-forge/locclass")`, but it installs a "locClassData" package instead.

I'm working on a Mac running macOS Ventura 13.4.1 .

How can I install this R package so that I can use it in RStudio?

Comment: Hi jayrendo! Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems like based on the errors (`directory not found for option '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib'`) you don't have gfortran installed

Comment: try installing this and see if it changes https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I installed gfortran using homebrew but I still get the same error message. Maybe it's installed in the wrong directory?